# How to update mongodump version?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to `mongodump` (export my Mongo DB) in order to export the db as a `.GZIP` file. However it rejected as:

```
Error parsing command line: unknown option gzip
```

My mongodump version is: `version 2.6.12`

I have heard that update the mongodump version to later than 3.x will repair this issue and it will be available to mongodump with gzip.

How to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: `mongodump` is included in MongoDB installations. If you upgrade your MongoDB, the tools (`mongodump`, `mongorestore`, `mongoexport`, etc.) will also be upgraded as a result.

Comment: Also note that MongoDB only supports binary upgrades between successive major versions. The current major version is 3.6.3. To upgrade from 2.6, you would need to upgrade from 2.6 -> 3.0 -> 3.2 -> 3.4 -> 3.6. Another option is to `mongodump` your data from 2.6 and `mongorestore` into a new 3.6 deployment.

Comment: @KevinAdistambha thanks for the answer.
So you say that I should backup the db and the restore each collection as version of 3.6 then it will be available to be --gzip ?

Comment: Yes that may be the quickest way to upgrade from 2.6 to 3.6, unless you have a lot of data in the multiple terabytes range.